# Web browser manipulation, iterate emails and get statistics data

Tags: email, browser, automation

I want to make a program that iterate through my emails and then get some statistics about them. Is there any programming language or tool I can use for this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), which has support for a variety of languages (e.g. Java, Python, Objective-C, C#, Javascript, Ruby, and more).  Under the hood, it's using [`webdriver`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) to drive the browser, and there are other language-specific tools that use webdriver for programatic browser manipulation (e.g. `watir-webdriver` in ruby).